# Google Cloud Talent Solution has stopped returning "matchingJobs"

Tags: google-cloud-talent-solution

Google Cloud Talent Solution - version 3.

I had a working project with indexed jobs. Calls to `response = build('jobs', 'v3').projects().jobs().search(...)` returned a list of jobs in `response.get('matchingJobs')`

But this afternoon, while `grand_total = response.get('totalSize', 0)` continues to gold the correct number of matches, a call to `response.get('matchingJobs')` return None.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue?

The service still returns accepts new jobs and returns job content correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A day later and this aspect of Google's Talent Solution has been fixed by Goggle.